# Scheme: pattern matching syntax

Tags: syntax, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am trying to do some fairly complicated pattern matching using match-lambda.  However I am having a lot of trouble deciphering the syntax for the patterns and the matches and Googling hasn't turned up any decent references.

One thing that seems like it ought to be simple is matching the string '(PARAMS: (y)) using this pattern:

```
(`(PARAMS: (,<arg>))
 <match>
```

But it doesn't work.

The pattern:

```
(`(PARAMS: ,<arg>)
 `<match>
```

matches '(PARAMS: y) but I would really like to be able to put the paramaters I am matching in brackets.

Strangely, the pattern:

```
(`(PARAMS: (y))
 `<match>
```

does not even match '(PARAMS: (y)).  It seems there is something about parentheses that I do not understand.

Comment: I wasn't registered before and I had to register to vote.  But now I am told that I don't have enough reputation to vote up an answer.  I'll just keep trying until I have enough reputation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you were asking me to click on the check mark, not the voting option.  Done.

Comment: awesome! many thanks. nag comment deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try posting a small complete program.  This works fine for me:

```
#lang racket

(match `(PARAMS: (y))
  [`(PARAMS: (,var)) 'yep]
  [otherise 'nope])
```

==>

```
'yep
```

(also, cf. comment to your question, above)